# getpreventdefault is deprecated - Caroussel stopped working

Tags: javascript

I have a caroussel slide made with a view and it was working fine until today. The block (with a view inside) just dissappeared from the front page.

I aggregated js files in the performance page... maybe that was it. But now I uncheked the option and cleared the cache many times and is still not working.

I'm getting this error from the console: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated

Does it has something to do with it?

Jquery update is 1.10

Answer (score 0):

try to use Jquery version 1.7.1, or 1.8

If this doesn't work you can try that function this way:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.defaultPrevented) return;
    // continue
});
```

If everything was working before, maybe is some other js script added and it is getting the error but the console is not showing it properly

Comment: It's not working. Where should I write that function? I added it to the views-carousel.tpl but nothing works...

Comment: Nevermind, got it!

Comment: Which solution did you use? Clear the cache if the function is not working and look for the error that you have and replace my code there